# How can I load another new Word document in the same Word window?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, ole

It seems that in the Microsoft Word object model, a Word document is bound to a Window, but I want to close the existing document and open a new one without closing the Word window. How can I do this?

Comment: What makes you think that's possible?

Comment: Okay, *why* do you want to do it? Amend your question to explain your actual goal, and we may be able to help you.

Comment: @Jonathan, I'm developing a Word addin which adds sidebars to Word window, and I need to reload different documents in the *same* Word window,  and when the Word window is closed the *state* of the sidebars will lost.

Comment: @Edwin I suspect it would be easier to redesign your addin so that it can maintain its state between windows.

Comment: @Jonathan, maybe this post describes my question better? If I can solve that problem I'll be able to solve this question! <br>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578556/put-multiple-word-document-windows-into-the-same-parent-window

Comment: Can you open the new file first and then close the old file?

Comment: @Knox, yes, when there is only one Word window; but when there are multiple Word window open, that will cause screen flicker.

Comment: Actually, knox's idea shouldn't cause any flicker. If you open a new window, it's on top and is the user focus, closing a background window shouldn't matter much at all at that point.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Word works differently when you have the SHOW ALL WINDOWS IN TASKBAR option checked or unchecked.

Comment: @drventure, you are right, but I'll have to change that Word option on the user's PC... Moreover, Word 2000 has no that option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me to close a document and open a document in the same window (I'm running the macro from *normal.dotm*):

```
Sub CloseOpenSameWindow()
    Dim d As Document: Set d = ActiveDocument
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    d.Close
    Application.Documents.Add Template:="C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Mydocument.docx"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Otaku, Word 2007 still flashes a lot with this method, with Word 2003 it's better...By flashing I mean you can see a window closes and another shows up. Thanks for letting me know the ScreenUpdating property though...

Comment: @Edwin: I'm on Word 2010 and I don't have any flashing - i.e. the window **doesn't** close - just the document closes and a new one is opened in it's stead in the same window.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't continue to test with Word 2010, because on word 2007 it flickers a lot. And yes, it doesn't close the window, looks like my initial assumption is wrong... Thanks for letting me know this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried File->Close ? That *should* close the file and leave the window open, allowing you to open another file in the same window, atleast thats how I remember it working.

Comment: Hi Diabl0658, that's true when there is only one Word document is open, otherwise  closing a document will result in closing that Word window as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Ctrl+w** (to close current window) and then **Ctrl+n** (to open new one)

Two Key Taps, thats all :)

Comment: Hi Akhil, I'm developing a word addin, and I need the original window remain in order to make the add-in work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it .close?

.exit quits the whole application?

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily use

```
Application.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = False
```

Which effectively makes Word into an MDI style application.

Comment: But then I'll have to change that Word option on the user's PC...Moreover, Word 2000 has no that option... do we have alternative options?

Comment: By "temporarily use" I meant: set a variable to the current value, change the setting to false, do your file swapping, then change the setting back to its original value. AFAIK, Word 2000 never had an MDI option, so I think you'll struggle with that version. But quite frankly, I think making your add-in cater for *every* version of Word will be fraught anyway.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, this will cause a problem, - my add-in use task panes and temporarily changes that option will cause problems, because when that option is off, I have multiple instance of my task panes; and when that option is on, only once task pane instance is allowed. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: @Edwin: Task panes are attached to window frames rather than documents, so when you switch to MDI mode there is only one window. You *could* record the state of task panes for each document first, then set them back to visible when you're done; but that's getting into the territory of managing your task panes, which would probably be a better way to handle this problem rather than changing the document viewing mode. Check out [this Microsoft video](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/cc338012.aspx) for a guide on managing task panes between Word documents.

Comment: @Antogony, Thanks for the further info. I wrote some test code to toggle the ShowWindowsInTaskbar property, and I noticed significant flickers of the Windows taskbar, the Word menubar and the Word window itself... Looks this would not work...

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the following for implementing your **add-in**:

- The add-in should not depends on the window mode (SDI or MDI)
- The add-in state should be saved to retain user customizations. Saving add-in state can be achieved by using XML, registry, INI or any other format.
- Every time a document is open the add-in should change to reflect the document state.
- The add-in should support multiple word Document instances.

See:

http://www.visualstudiodev.com/visual-studio-tools-for-office/word-addin-multiple-instances-of-word-running-48076.shtml

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa189710(v=office.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa189710%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try this

in the Normal.ThisDocument

```
Sub main()
    Me.Close
    Documents.Add
End Sub
```

this will close the current document and open a new document. you need to handle the save for current document