# Prevent the entire screen from updating

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Edit 1: Actually, I was only wanted to avoid the the flicker caused by closing a Word document and opening another one. But now it looks this approach is not feasible.

Greetings, is it possible to Prevent the entire screen (not only the desktop) from updating? The question is derived from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574825/load-another-new-word-document-in-the-same-word-window-how). What I want to do is that, in my Word add-in, to lock the entire screen update when I'm closing a Word document and opening another one, and re-enable the update when I'm done.

An idea would be:

1. Get the image of the entire screen (how?);
2. Show a top-most window to show the screen image captured in step 1, to cover the entire screen;
3. Do my job and close the top-most window when done.

Is it possible? Or do you have other better ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You do realise that this is a very bad idea, I trust.

Comment: A word of warning: such behavior of an application (worse, an add-in to a word-processing application) could be considered borderline malware ("hijacks controls of other applications and/or window manager? Check. Prevents user from operating other applications? Check."). I trust that your intentions are pure, but the first time this happens to me as an user, I'll be paranoid to the max and up in arms ("I installed this add-in and now it prevents the screen from updating, what is it trying to hide from me?!"), unless that transition is indeed the point of your add-in.

Comment: Open the new document first. Once it has appeared, close the old document. No need to lock the screen at all.

Comment: @Piskvor, but it's just a matter of a fraction of a second, and it happens during an operation within my add-in, other apps should be in 'static' state during this operation. My intension is to make the user don't notice the flicker caused by switching windows, when re-opening a Word document.

Comment: @Rob, that still cause flickers, I tried...

Comment: Whatever this add-in is I don't want it coming anywhere near my computer

Comment: whatever you are trying to solve with your solution... find a different solution. this is super disgusting. spend your effort looking for a good-bear solution.

Comment: @Edwin: You mean it's only _supposed_ to be a fraction of a second.  But consider that if anything goes wrong (which, in Automation, could happen for reasons outside of your code) you've hung the user's computer.

Comment: @Edwin: "other apps should be in 'static' state during this operation" Do tell, how do you suggest to pause all the other apps? Last I checked, Windows is not single-threaded since version 3.1 - unless you mean "by definition, there must be nothing more interesting than MY program, when it is running"

Comment: I am upvoting the question because the comments are very worthwhile.

Comment: @David, I didn't initially, but now I do...

Comment: @Edwin, great, that is why I upvoted both your question and your comment.

Comment: It is possible... with DirectDraw. Actually, the funniest thing, Winword add-on which demands exclusive access to the primary surface ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to prevent screen updates:

```
SendMessage(GetDesktopWindow, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);
```

to re-enable screen updates:

```
SendMessage(GetDesktopWindow, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);
```

Comment: And what about all the apps that are also top level windows?

Comment: And what if your add-in crashes between the first and the second message? (Of course *your* code never crashes. Well, what if Word crashes, taking your add-in with it?) Will this require a login-logout, a reboot, or an even more drastic action to fix? (not trolling, just curious)

Comment: Thanks glob, it seem can disable the painting of the desktop, but it will cause error, and the painting can't be restored with the second line of code you provided. Maybe this method can lead to unpredictable problems...

Comment: @Edwin maybe the entire misguided idea can lead to very predictable problems......

Comment: @David, you are right, I've been scratching my head for a solution for my problem (reopening a Word document in the same Word window), so maybe this is not a good idea...

Answer (score 7):

Don't.

No app, plugin, or other very nice piece of code can never be so special as to intrude - even for a short time - what the user owns: his UI.

[The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) ([Raymond Chen](http://microsoftjobsblog.com/blog/raymond-chen/)) has a few very nice posts in this, varying from [LockWindowUpdate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/23/1747713.aspx), to [locking gadges in place](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/07/21/10040699.aspx) and other [user-hostile features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/01/922449.aspx).

Living in a multi-threaded world, means you should expect that your user will do multiple things at the same time.

Locking anything for purposes as "to make it look nice" - even for a very short period of time - is a complete no-no.

Your request is just the first step towards the dreaded system-modal dialog "Are you sure you want to do this bad thing to your computer?" with buttons `Yes` and `No`, where `Yes` is the default button, in the midst of the user typing a long story, pressing the space bar.

--jeroen

Comment: +1 "yeah, let's disable the UI here just for a seco--Word has encountered a problem and needs to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience." @Edwin: The UI is disabled, and the process that should have re-enabled it doesn't exist anymore. Now what? (and don't say "Windows users are used to rebooting," this is not 1998 anymore)